# Output image in different directory with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, png

I have a PNG image located outside of public_html. I want to put that picture in a `<img>` tag. Does anyone know how to do that with php?

Comment: Woops. I meant a < img > tag.

Comment: That's not directly possible. You either have to use a `.htaccess` rule to internally direct the URL, or use a PHP file to read the contents of the file, and echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an intermediary that outputs the image, sending the correct headers:

```
<?php

$path = '/some/sanizied/path.png';

header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
// other headers like Length are nice, too.
readfile( $path );
```

There are also X-Sendfile and X-Accel-Redirect headers that can instruct your web server to deliver another file. This removes some PHP overhead.

Comment: Cool. Just take some precautions if you let the user supply the path in the URI. For example, run realpath() on the supposed path and make sure the result is inside the expected directory.

Answer (score 0):

i think your really asking just a plain html question, tho I'd need to see your actual code to give you a accurate answer.

If the png image file is located in another file/directory location, your code might looking something like this.

```
<img src='../file2/happy.png' alt='happy' />
```

The above will go up a directory level, then go into the folder 'file2' and point to the happy.png image file there.

Nothing to do with php when it comes down to specifying directory location of an image file, unless your trying to dynamically create the location which changes regularly.

Comment: All files in `public_html` are accessible through the root of a website. `../../../../` at the root of the website points to the root, which is the same `public_html` directory.

Comment: That won't work, because the folder is not located in public_html.